# How to download table from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, download

I would like to download a table from Google Cloud Platform. For example, [this table](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=erudite-marker-539&page=table&d=nyc_taxi_redacted&p=alien-climber-851&redirect_from_classic=true&ws=!1m28!1m4!4m3!1serudite-marker-539!2sJEMS16!3sinventor_raw!1m3!3m2!1salien-climber-851!2snyc_taxi_redacted!1m3!3m2!1serudite-marker-539!2sJEMS16!1m4!4m3!1serudite-marker-539!2sJEMS16!3sassignee_disambiguation!1m4!4m3!1spatents-public-data!2scpc!3sdefinition!1m4!4m3!1salien-climber-851!2snyc_taxi_redacted!3sjfk_dropoffs&t=jfk_dropoffs). I tried `Export - Export to GCS`, but couldn't figure it out. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need export you're table from cloud sql/Bigquery to cloud storage bucket using export options and file format, the  you can download from cloud storage

Comment: Thanks! I get this message: "[my email address] does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project."

Comment: Or actually, `Access Denied: Project [...]: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project [...].`

Comment: if your trying to get data from another project/ bigquery dataset  ( not public ) then you can not get it until you have permission in that project, that project owner needs to add you there then it will work, Hope it will help you